# Overriding instance variable when moving duplicated code to superclass Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm writing a cellular automata simulation program, and I currently have several subclasses of Cell objects corresponding to each type of Simulation I want to run and each subclass has a setNeighbors method that another class calls to set the neighbors of a Cell depending on its position in the grid.

```
public abstract class LifeCell extends Cell{
    protected List<LifeCell> myNeighbors

    public void setNeighbors(List<LifeCell> neighbors){
        myNeighbors=neighbors;
    }

public abstract class FireCell extends Cell{
    protected List<FireCell> myNeighbors

    public void setNeighbors(List<FireCell> neighbors){
        myNeighbors=neighbors;
    }
```

etc.
The setNeighbors method is currently duplicated across subclasses and I want to move the list of neighbors into the Cell superclass as a List of abstract Cell objects. The code in my Cell superclass currently looks like this:

```
public abstract class Cell {
    List<Cell> myNeighbors;

    public void setNeighbors(List<Cell> neighbors){
        myNeighbors = neighbors;
    }
}
```

However, it's important that the list of neighboring Cells in the subclasses be of the same type of Cell as each particular subclass (GameOfLifeCells should only have GameOfLifeCells as their neighbors). It doesn't seem like it's possible for me to declare a List of neighbors in the superclass and then override that instance variable with a list of typeCell in the subclass.

How else would I be able to express the relation that every Cell has neighbors of the same type and still be able to access this List from the superclass?

Comment: Can you write your code so we can help you ?

Comment: please provide concrete code examples and a clear question

Comment: Make it `? Extends Cell` ...

Comment: Making the list ?Extends Cell allows you to run setNeighbors on any subclass of Cell, but how would the subclass of Cell know what type of Cell its neighbors are?

Comment: @Jazzy It won't. You'd have to check programmatically. But it would determine the possible types at runtime to one subclass at a time. But you are right, it will not solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe this trail will help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little something like this:

```
abstract class TestSuper<T extends TestSuper>{
    protected List<T> myList;
    public void method( List<T> param ){
        myList = param;
    }
}

class TestChild extends TestSuper<TestChild>{}
```